# Can not delete from @ElementCollection

Tags: java, hibernate

In User.java ive got a map:

```
@Entity
public class User{
...
@ElementCollection
private Map<Competency,Float> competenciesValue = new HashMap<Competency,Float>();
}
```

and got Competency class

```
@Entity
public class Competency{
..
}
```

This is a many to many relationship. Many users can have many competencies.

And now wherever i try to delete any of my COMPETENCY i get a foreign key error. How to deal with it ?

**Stacktrace :**

```
Hibernate: delete from Competency where id=?
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1451, SQLState: 23000
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`CT2_szet`.`User_competenciesValue`, CONSTRAINT `FK_887tayi9xe3w6xw8jv2cui829` FOREIGN KEY (`competenciesValue_KEY`) REFERENCES `Competency` (`id`))
Jun 05, 2014 4:13:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/CompetenceTool] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`CT2_szet`.`User_competenciesValue`, CONSTRAINT `FK_887tayi9xe3w6xw8jv2cui829` FOREIGN KEY (`competenciesValue_KEY`) REFERENCES `Competency` (`id`))
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
```

Comment: Please provide a full stacktrace so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

The below is the problem

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(CT2_szet.User_competenciesValue, CONSTRAINT FK_887tayi9xe3w6xw8jv2cui829 FOREIGN KEY (competenciesValue_KEY) REFERENCES Competency (id))
```

First delete the `parent` row, then delete the corresponding row in `Comptency`

Comment: Of course i need to remove parent row but how to do that, being given only a Competency entity? I could do ugly jpa query but how to do it nice in hibernate?

Comment: Then using the competent entity read its parent, then delete the parent first.